# How to div stay visible on hover when i have space between?

Tags: html, css

I have problem with hover out. When I try to hover the child div it disappears.

I want space between these two div as in my fiddle. This is my fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/rc4tpug6/1/

```
<div class='user-data'>
bbbbb
    <div class='test'>
        aaaa
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is when I try to hover on "aaa" it disappear because it have space between it and the parent, but I need that space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because there is a gap between the two divs caused by your `top:30px` setting.

Change that to top:100%

```css
.user-data {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom:1em;
}
.test {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.user-data:hover .test {
  display: block;
      }
```

```html
<div class='user-data'>
  bbbbb
  <div class='test'>
    aaaa
  </div>
</div>
```

If you require extra spacing between the two divs, add `padding-top` to the child element or `padding-bottom` to the parent.

Comment: i need that gap ... i need space between those two with 30px;

Comment: is there any other solution without padding but with top:30px?

Comment: No...you can't hover a gap between two elements since you would no longer be hovering either element.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the help of pseudo-elements if padding cannot be applied. Not sure if this will work for all scenarios.

```css
.user-data{
  position:relative;
}
.test{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.test::before{
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
}
.user-data:hover .test{
  display:block;
 
}
```

```html
<div class='user-data'>
  bbbbb
    <div class='test'>
        aaaa
    </div>
</div>
```